Visual Studio Compile Projects with Batch-Script with Special Characters
I'm using a batch script to compile multiple Visual Studio projects in Debug and Release.
For that I'm using the following Code:
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"
devenv "%%s" /build Debug
devenv "%%s" /build Release

When building specific projects with special characters, I get the following error:
Invalid character in the specified encoding.

After letting the script run I tried opening the project and it now looks like this:

Before running the script it looked like this, and I was able to build the project manually:

The problem is the character ß it seems.
Does anyone have a solution or a workaround for this problem? I have a lot of projects with this character and renaming every class would be tedious.

Maybe wrong codepage (chcp) for cmd/batch?

Try chcp 65001 > NUL command at beginning of your script

I tried chcp 65001, 850 and 1252. All of them have the same outcome with the same error message

When a .csproj file is not saved with UTF-8 encoding, Visual Studio might have trouble correctly processing special characters during the build process.

The problem was that the .csproj file was not encoded in UTF-8.
Running the batch script in PowerShell with the following command:
powershell -Command "Get-Content '%%f' | Set-Content -Path '%%f' -Encoding UTF8"
before compiling the project fixed the problem.
